# MapStruct: How to set default value only if source value is not null?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Usually MapStruct only sets the target field if the source field is not `null`. However, if using a `@Mapping` with a `constant` then the generated code sets the target field in any case. I would like MapStruct to only set the target field if the source field is not null, but then to a constant value. 
My current best guess would be to work with the `qualifiedByName` clause, like so:

```
@Mapping(target = "targetField", source = "sourceField", qualifiedByName = METHOD_NAME)
```

And the defined method:

```
@Named(METHOD_NAME)
static String mapTargetField(String sourceField) {
    if (sourceField!= null) {
        return CONSTANT;
    }
    return null;
}
```

For this simple concept, does somebody know a shorter way to do that?

Comment: You can use an expression.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way can be achieved with expression and ternary operator:

```
@Mapping(target = "targetField", expression = "java(null == source.getField() ? CONSTANT : source.getField())")
```

However, the cons are that it can be more difficult to refactor. You will need to take care every time you will change the name of the field and related getter.

If you need to use it on one field, expression can be ok, but if this is a common behaviour for many fields, I prefer your approach, which is centralised and you can easily change the behaviours.